# How to avoid different versions of pip installing binaries in the same directory?

Tags: python, pip

I work on Linux, and I have two locally compiled versions of Python 3.
Python 3.6 was configured with `--prefix=${HOME}` and Python 3.8 with `--prefix=${HOME}/python3.8`:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ which python3.6
/home/bli/bin/python3.6
bli@naples:~$ which python3.8
/home/bli/python3.8/bin/python3.8
```

The corresponding `pip` commands are both in my `~/.local/bin` directory:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ which pip3.6
/home/bli/.local/bin/pip3.6
bli@naples:~$ which pip3.8
/home/bli/.local/bin/pip3.8
```

When I install python packages using `pip3.6` or `pip3.8`, the libraries are installed separately in `/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` and `/home/bli/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`.

However, **binaries seem to get installed in the same `~/.local/bin` directory**, which leads to files being overwritten.

For instance, after `pip3.8 install ipython`, the previously installed `ipython3` command was replaced:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ ipython3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
3.8.0a2 (default, Mar  6 2019, 14:42:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
bli@naples:~$ head -1 /home/bli/.local/bin/ipython3
#!/home/bli/python3.8/bin/python3.8
```

I can get back the previous one with `pip3.6 install ipython --upgrade`:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ ipython3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
3.6.4 (default, Feb 14 2018, 18:35:27) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
bli@naples:~$ head -1 /home/bli/.local/bin/ipython3
#!/home/bli/bin/python3.6
```

But, obviously, this is not very convenient. I don't want to run pip every time I switch between my two installations.

I would prefer not to have to work with virtual environments. I want two separate python3 installations. **Is it possible to avoid such interference?**

In case this is relevant, I have the following `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ cat ~/.pydistutils.cfg
[install]
optimize=1
[build_ext]
include_dirs=${HOME}/include
library_dirs=${HOME}/lib
rpath=${HOME}/lib
user=1
```

And my `get_python.sh` script to install python from source is as follows:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prog="python"
progname="Python"
# It is possible to set the version in the `${VERSION}` environment variable to override the default.
# example: `VERSION="2.7.12" get_python.sh`
if [[ ${VERSION} ]]
then
    version="${VERSION}"
else
    version="2.7.12"
fi

if [[ ${RELEASE} ]]
then
    release="${RELEASE}"
else
    release=""
fi

mkdir -p ${HOME}/src
cd ${HOME}/src
# In case it's already there, remove it
rm -rf ${progname}-${version}*
# Download it
wget --continue https://www.python.org/ftp/${prog}/${version}/${progname}-${version}${release}.tar.xz
tar -xvJf ${progname}-${version}${release}.tar.xz
(
cd ${progname}-${version}${release}
[ ${PREFIX} ] || PREFIX=${HOME}
export PYTHONPATH=${PREFIX}
./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --prefix=${PREFIX} CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native -fomit-frame-pointer" CPPFLAGS="-I${HOME}/include" LDFLAGS="-L${PREFIX}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib"
make
make install
)
```

Which I used as follows:

```
VERSION="3.6.4" get_python.sh
VERSION="3.8.0" RELEASE="a2" PREFIX="${HOME}/python3.8" get_python.sh
```

Comment: "I would prefer not to have to work with virtual environments" => why ??? venvs are easy to setup, easy to work with and they solve quite a few compat issues...

Comment: On its own, `pip` really isn't smart enough to pull off what you're looking for. You might check out a tool like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) if you're dead set against using virtualenvs.

Comment: @9769953 I may be wrong, but it seems that what you describe only concerns libraries, not binaries.

Comment: @bli Which binaries are you talking about: because both pip and ipython are executable as modules, and those are the ones I see mentioned in your question.

Comment: Do pip installed "binaries" always take the form of a simple wrapper that imports a module, and that it is always equivalent to use python -m instead?

Comment: It's actually somewhat of a problem that many installs don't *also* create separate <name>3.8 executables, next to <name> itself. pip does, and Python itself, but that's about it.

Comment: @bli it really depends on what you're installing. The packages you need may all have such binaries (often, this "binary" itself is a 5-to-10-line Python script wrapping around a call into the package itself. See `pip` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is totally possible. Use

```
python3.6 -m pip install <whatever>
```

and

```
python3.8 -m pip install <whatever>
```

Python will take care of the rest: packages are installed in separate lib/pythonx.y/ directories, for example.

As long as the minor releases are different, you can have a whole zoo of Python installations next to each other.

---

This works similar for `ipython`:

```
python3.6 -m ipython
```

(or `python3.6 -m jupyter console`)

and similar for Python 3.8:

```
# pick the one that works
python3.8 -m ipython
python3.8 -m jupyter console
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that I can chose which version of ipython to run by importing the corresponding module in the chosen python interpreter. However, what I would like is to have separate directories for the binaries.

Comment: @bli Why?  ‍     ‍     ‍

Comment: I find it a bit dissatisfying to see that files get overwritten. And also, I'm not sure this technique would always work.

Comment: I agree that it is not nice, and it would be much better if packages that come with executables have an option (through `pip`) to install in a user selected directory (and a shortcut to install it in the same directory as the Python or pip executable).

Comment: This is the (best) suggestion I have to offer (other than using virtual environments). Though I've found relatively few packages that also install executables: most are really libraries (packages), and luckily avoid installing extra binaries (notorious exception and example that I'm aware of: astropy).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem can be solved (at least for `ipython3`) by setting the `install-scripts` option of the `[install]` section of a version-specific `distutils/distutils.cfg` file.

In the present case, the following seems to work in order to have `pip3.8` install executables in the same directory as the one of the `python3.8` interpreter itself:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ cat ~/python3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/distutils.cfg
[install]
prefix=/home/bli/python3.8
install-scripts=/home/bli/python3.8/bin
```

This can be automated by adding the following after the `make install` step in my `get_python.sh` script:

```bash
distutils_cfg="${PREFIX}/lib/${prog}$(echo ${VERSION} | cut -d "." -f 1,2)/distutils/distutils.cfg"
echo "setting ${distutils_cfg}"
echo "[install]" >> ${distutils_cfg}
echo "prefix=${PREFIX}" >> ${distutils_cfg}
echo "install-scripts=${PREFIX}/bin" >> ${distutils_cfg}
```

After `pip3.6 install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall ipython` and `pip3.8 install --upgrade --force-reinstall ipython`, I have the following separate executables:

```bash
bli@naples:~$ head -1 .local/bin/ipython3 
#!/home/bli/bin/python3.6
bli@naples:~$ head -1 python3.8/bin/ipython3 
#!/home/bli/python3.8/bin/python3.8
```

I suspect it might be cleaner to also set the `install-lib` option to `${PREFIX}/lib`, so that the same directory is used as the one created during the `make install` step.

See https://bouktin.blogspot.com/2012/04/configure-pydistutilscfg-python.html for more details about the available options.